# Radgrid insertItem from client side

Tags: telerik, radgrid

How can i get radgrid insert items from clientside.
I have used the following code, but its not working.

```
            var mode = rgBoxLimits.get_isItemInserted();
            var insertItems;
            var dpToDate;
            if (mode) {
                insertItems= rgBoxLimits.get_insertItem();
                dpToDate = insertItems[0].findElement("dtToDate");  //Not working
            }
```

For edit items, i have the following code and its working fine.

```
                var editedItems = rgBoxLimits.get_editItems();
                var dpToDate = editedItems[0].findElement("dtToDate");
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are running the `get_isItemInserted()` and `get_insertedItem()` method  on a `RadGrid` object, while they are methods for a `GridTableView` object. [See the RadGrid Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html) for more info.

Try this:

```
function getItems(sender, args) {
    var myRadGrid = document.getElementById("MainContent_RadGrid1");
    var grid = window.$find("MainContent_RadGrid1");

    var mode = grid.get_masterTableView().get_isItemInserted();
    mode = true;
    var insertItems;
    var dpToDate;
    if (mode) {
        insertItems = grid.get_masterTableView().get_insertItem();
        dpToDate = insertItems[0].findElement("dtToDate"); //Not working
    }
}
```